# Aggregation level is off (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, window, aggregate

I have Order data for 2 customers and their order. And I am trying to calculate what the sum for the price is for every customter for that specific order only for product N

Table:

[image]

This is my query:

```
select Customer_ID, Order_ID, Sales_Date,
sum(Price) over (partition by Customer_ID, Order_ID order by Customer_ID, Order_ID)
from orders
group by 1,2,3, Price
order by;
```

For some reason I do not understand it gives me several rows per same customer. I am trying to get only one row generated per customer and order for product N

This is my current Output:
[image]

Desired Outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using window functions?  I think you just want aggregation:

```
select Customer_ID, Order_ID, Sales_Date,
       sum(Price)
from orders
group by 1,2,3;
```

If you only want one product, add `where product = 'N'`.

Comment: I see that I was trying to make thing more complicated than they are. If I would want to generate a price column for each of the product - would you suggest to write a separate CTE for each in the same manner as above and combine in a final select statement? Or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: @sweti . . . You would use conditional aggregation if you wanted a separate price for each product.  I would suggest tha tyou ask a new question if that is what you want.